# Why doesn't this equals method properly override the object.equals method?

Tags: java, equals

```
public class Person{
    private String name;
    public Person(String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }
    public boolean equals (Person p){
         return p.name.equals(this.name);
    }
}
```

The equals method does not properly override the object.equals method. Why?

Comment: Did you try to add the `@Override` annotation and see if the compiler complains? What's the signature of the equals method herited from the Object class?

Comment: In order to override, it needs to take an `Object`

Comment: Writing a correct `equals` function is actually more difficult than it seems, especially if `Person` could be subclassed later.  See [this link](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html).

Answer (score 2):

The `equals` method recieves an `Object`, not a `Person`, and should return `false` for any argument that isn't a `Person` instance. E.g.:

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object o) {
     if (!(o instanceof Person)) {
         return false;
     }
     Person p = (Person) o;
     return p.name.equals(this.name);
}
```

Comment: I'm a little wary about "should return `false` for any argument not a `Person`" simply because it *could* be a functional requirement that `Person` is equatable to a different type (although the chances are likely very small)

Comment: It **could**, theoretically, be a requirement, but I've yet to see any project that actually required it. Moreover, the OP's implementation suggests that two `Person` instances are equal if they have the same `name` - objects that aren't `Person`s are not applicable anyway.

Comment: Instead of `!(o instanceof Person)` you could also write (`this.getClass() != o.getClass()`) which is stricter if `o`'s class is a subclass of `Person`.  But that approach isn't always right, either.  http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html has a good discussion of this.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the signature of the `equals()` method in `Object` is

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
```

Notice the type of the input is `Object`. Technically an override cannot be of a subtype, it must be of the same type. Your method is an overload instead of an override.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the `equals` method is

```
public boolean equals(Object other);
```

If you think about it that's because you might want to compare the object to objects of different types.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

is the syntax

But remember to override the hashcode method as well.

Answer (score 0):

When overriding a method everything should be same as the method which you are trying to override.

In your case equals method is using Person but originally it takes an Object Type.

> The overriding method has the same name, number and type of
>   parameters, and return type as the method that it overrides.

Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html